# Variable doesn't save the current List size

Tags: java, variables, arraylist

So I have this piece of code here:

```
List<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();
int size = s1.size();

s1.add("A");
s1.add("B");
System.out.println(size);
s1.add("C");
s1.add("D");
System.out.println(size);
```

And that's the output:

```
0
0
```

But it should be:

```
2
4
```

What it the problem? Why doesn't the variable size get the current List size when I call her?

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: you need to call "s1.size();" after very change.

Comment: you needed to update your `size` before you print it by assigning again s1.size() to `size` variable.

Comment: `int` is a primitive type, it is not pointing to a shared value or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time you did this  `int size = s1.size();` the list was empty. so size is a primitive value that is not going to be updated automatically according to the list's sizes!

You need to refresh that value every time the list changes its size!

```
s1.add("A");
s1.add("B");
size = s1.size();   // update size
System.out.println(size);
s1.add("C");
s1.add("D");
size = s1.size();   // update size
System.out.println(size);
```

Answer (score 2):

`size` contains the value that was assigned to it when `int size = s1.size();` was executed, which is 0, since the list was empty at the time.

It isn't modified automatically when the list is modified. It has no association with the size of the list.

You do have a variable whose value is updated when the list size is changed. That's the `size` variable of the `ArrayList` class, whose value you get when you call the `size()` method:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this list
 */
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

Therefore you don't need your variable. Simply call `s1.size()` to get the current size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

To print correct size you should always use `s1.size();` in your case. as list is modifiable, hence storing it in a local variable will not help unless you have unmodifiable list. As local variable is not updated every-time new entry is added/removed in the list.

You should call `s1.size();` after adding data to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use below to get size of the list.

```
System.out.println(s1.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

The size you are printing is a variable which has already been assigned a value well before any value was added to the arraylist, hence, the size variable will always print value 0 anywhere you use it (unless youy reassign any value).

The one which you require is the size method of List; which is accessed by `Arraylist_Name.size()`

So, when you are printing the values, you should use `s1.size()` which will give the current size of the ArrayList.

Or, you need to assign the new ArrayList sizes everytime to your size variable, so that it is in sync with the actual ArrayList size.